# jQuery .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple jQuery script and the .hide() is not properly rendering.  You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/2/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: your jsFiddle is set-up using Mootools when you are using jQuery syntax. You can check your console error logs before posting.

Comment: The question isn't inappropriate so much as mistagged.  It should be tagged under "jsfiddle".  Done.

Comment: if .hide() wasn't working, you wouldn't be the first to discover that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fixed that for you](http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/5/).  You didn't have jQuery selected on the left (you had mooTools).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the jQuery library selected on jsfiddle.  Works for me once I add the library:

http://jsfiddle.net/YR6fL/

Answer (score 1):

You can not expect jQuery methods to run with not jquery but Mootools loaded. Check your fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/VBhYT/8/

Answer (score 1):

update the JQuery library on the left side

Answer (score 0):

Set your fiddle to use jQuery instead of Mootools and the `.hide()` works http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VBhYT/6/.

Answer (score 0):

it started working when I updated the library to use Jquery 1.6.2. you had it set on mootools.

here: http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/VBhYT/4/

Answer (score -1):

try this
      .css('display', 'none')

Comment: This is not his issue.  `jQuery.hide()` works perfectly fine.